# Change Backcolor of button, based on Button name

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently writing a program for laboratory weighing.
On my form there is a grid of 42 positions (7 rows of 6 samples = 1 rack), where each position is a button, with name "Buttonxx" (where xx stands for position number, e.g. Button01, Button02, ... , Button42)

All the information comes from a Oracle Database, through an SQL.

I want to change the Backcolor of specific button based on a piece of information that is returned by the SQL, namely if that sample has to be weighed or not (ToDo = "Y" or "N") for a certain laboratory analysis (= "TitrType" in code)

E.g. In the code below, if for a certain rack only position 23 needs to be weighed (ToDo= "Y") for TAN (= analysis/TitrType), then only the backcolor of that button ("Button23") should be changed to LightSkyBlue

I get the correct information from the SQL and am able to change the name of a virtual button into the name of the position that is ToDo: DummyBtn.Name = "Button23"

But the Backcolor doesn't change for some reason.

p.s.: I'm only novice programmer, so feel free to ask for more code or information if you need it.

```
Public Sub PrFillSampleGrid(TitrType As String, ByRef RS As System.Data.DataSet)
        Dim Pos As Integer = 0
        Dim TODO As String = ""

           For x = 0 To RS.Tables("test").Rows.Count - 1
            Pos = RS.Tables("test").Rows(x).Item("SERIESPOS")
            TODO = RS.Tables("test").Rows(x).Item("TODO")   
            For y = 1 To 42
                Dim DummyBtn As New Button
                Select Case TODO.ToUpper
                    Case TODO = "YES", "Y"

                        If y = Pos Then
                            DummyBtn.Name = "Button" & y
                            Select Case TitrType
                                Case Is = "AcIn"
                                    DummyBtn.BackColor = Color.Orange
                                Case Is = "TAN"
                                    DummyBtn.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
                                Case Is = "TBN"
                                    DummyBtn.BackColor = Color.Crimson
                                Case Is = "TBN2"
                                    DummyBtn.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                            End Select
                        End If
                    Case TODO = "NO", "N"
                        DummyBtn.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
                End Select
            Next y
        Next x
    End Sub
```

Comment: are you missing `Me.Controls.Add(DummyBtn)`

Comment: It is missing in the FrmMain.Designer, yes. But when I add it there, I get an Error, stating that "DummyBtn" is not declared.

Comment: I think he meant it is missing from within your  `For y` loop.

Comment: I've also tried to add it in the procedure (so in the y loop) itself by using code below: 
Dim DummyBtn as new Button
FrmMain.Controls.add(DummyBtn)

Comment: You seem to be assuming that if you create a new button and then change its name to that of an existing button then you're working with the existing button. Is that right?

Comment: Enigmativity, that it the idea yes :D

Comment: You've got other issues here.  I am guessing if you click one of these buttons - nothing happens.  Also, how are you positioning them?

Comment: You need to be adding the buttons to a `Container` control for them to appear on the form.  Are they even rendering?  If so, then you have omitted code in your post and this makes it hard to work out exactly what is going on.

Comment: Just naming a button the same as an existing button just means you now have two buttons with the same name. You need to do a `FindControl(...)` to locate an existing button.

Comment: Joehanna, the "regular" buttons (Button1 until Button 42) are declared on the main Form and are rendered.
The DummyBtn is just for determining the correct, real button of which the backcolor should change, in a specific situation

Comment: @Enigmativity I tried that, but VB2013 doesn't have that command. I've also tried FrmMain.Controls.Find(DummyBtn.name, True) , but how do I compare what I find to all other buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
Public Sub PrFillSampleGrid(TitrType As String, ByRef RS As System.Data.DataSet)
    For x = 0 To RS.Tables("test").Rows.Count - 1
        Dim Pos = CInt(RS.Tables("test").Rows(x).Item("SERIESPOS"))
        Dim TODO = CStr(RS.Tables("test").Rows(x).Item("TODO"))
        For y = 1 To 42
            For Each DummyBtn In Me.Controls.Find("Button" & y.ToString(), True).OfType(Of Button)()
                Select Case TODO.ToUpper
                    Case "YES", "Y"
                        If y = Pos Then
                            Select Case TitrType
                                Case Is = "AcIn"
                                    DummyBtn.BackColor = Color.Orange
                                Case Is = "TAN"
                                    DummyBtn.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
                                Case Is = "TBN"
                                    DummyBtn.BackColor = Color.Crimson
                                Case Is = "TBN2"
                                    DummyBtn.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                            End Select
                        End If
                    Case "NO", "N"
                        DummyBtn.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
                End Select
            Next
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

The key change I made is the line `For Each DummyBtn In Me.Controls.Find("Button" & y.ToString(), True).OfType(Of Button)()`. This searches for the existing buttons with the name `"Button" & y` on the form and assigns the existing button to `DummyBtn`.

The other thing I did was put `Option Strict On` on the top of your code. This immediately highlighted a bunch of other errors in your code which I fixed.

It's advisable to always use `Option Strict On` as it puts VB into a strict typing mode and many many errors will be eliminated. Your line `Case TODO = "YES", "Y"` is an example of code which might seem correct, but isn't. It was evaluation to `Case "True", "Y"` or `Case "False", "Y"` with `Option Strict Off`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your first paragraph made it work for me. I was also able to use that to reinitialize my form, when I load another sample rack.

Comment: Doesn't the `For Each` operate on a single button each time?  Wouldn't it make more sense to do something like this:  `Dim DummyBtn As Button = Me.Controls.Find("Button" & y.ToString(), True).OfType(Of Button)()` and then check it for null before using it?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - `Controls.Find` returns an array of controls, then `OfType` reduces the array to an enumerable of zero of more buttons. The result is never `null` (or `Nothing`). Using `For Each` just iterates over the zero of more buttons (in practice probably just one though).

Comment: @Enigmativity - Thanks for the clarification.  I was not sure about that.  Then perhaps using `FirstOrDefault` may be appropriate.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - You could use `.FirstOrDefault()`, but why don't you like the `For Each` loop?

Comment: @Enigmativity - It just seems weird to loop over a collection of one item.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - It's not one item, it's zero or more. It's just likely to be only one.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your `Select`/`Case` statement.  You don't need the `Is =` as this implies you have objects and you are testing equality.  The value you are testing is a `String` (which is a `Value Type`) which is a straight comparison.

Simply use this:-

```
Select Case TitrType
  Case "AcIn"
    DummyBtn.BackColor = Color.Orange
  Case "TAN"
    DummyBtn.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
  Case = "TBN"
    DummyBtn.BackColor = Color.Crimson
  Case = "TBN2"
    DummyBtn.BackColor = Color.Yellow
End Select
```

Comment: I will look into it, although the Select Case itself seems to be working.
When I debug, I go to the correct Case.
Only the color change doesn't work.

Comment: The OP's issue is that the buttons already exist on the form, but he doesn't know how to get a reference to his existing buttons.

Comment: My second answer addresses that issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using class level declarations for buttons, then `DummyBtn` is never "connected" to them.

You need to do something like this before you assign the `BackColor`:

```
'Get a handle to the actual button
DummyBtn = CType(Me.ContainerName.Controls("Button" & y), Button)
```

Move `Dim DummyBtn As New Button` to be above the `For y` loop and replace it with this:-

```
Dim DummyBtn As Button
```

Comment: It seems odd to me that I need to do a CType to Button (for DummyBtn), as I already did a Dim DummyBtn as Button a few lines above. Or am I seeing this wrong.

Comment: The CType is necessary because the `Controls` property simply returns an object of type `Control` and the CType is necessary to safely cast it to the `Button` object we declared ("DummyBtn")